# Using json_extract in sqlite to pull data from parent and child objects

Tags: json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I'm starting to explore the JSON1 library for sqlite and have been so far successful in the basic queries I've created.  I'm now looking to create a more complicated query that pulls data from multiple levels.

Here's the example JSON object I'm starting with (and most of the data is very similar).

```json
{
  "height": 140.0,
  "id": "cp",
  "label": {
    "bind": "cp_label"
  },
  "type": "color_picker",
  "user_data": {
    "my_property": 2
  },
  "uuid": "948cb959-74df-4af8-9e9c-c3cb53ac9915",
  "value": {
    "bind": "cp_color"
  },
  "width": 200.0
}
```

This json object is buried about seven levels deep in a json structure and I pulled it from the larger json construct using an sql statement like this:

```
SELECT value FROM forms, json_tree(forms.formJSON, '$.root') 
WHERE type = 'object'
    AND json_extract(value, '$.id') = @sControlID

// In this example, @sControlID is a variable that represents the `id` value we're looking for, which is 'cp'
```

But what I really need to pull from this object are the following:

- the value from key `type` ("color_picker" in this example)
- the values from keys `bind` ("cp_color" and "cp_label" in this example)
- the keys `value` and `label` (which have values of `{"bind":"<string>"}` in this example)

For that last item, the key name (`value` and `label` in this case) can be any number of keywords, but no matter the keyword, the value will be an object of the form `{"bind":"<some_string>"}`.  Also, there could be multiple keys that have a `bind` object associated with them, and I'd need to return all of them.
For the first two items, the keywords will always be `type` and `bind`.

With the json example above, I'd ideally like to retrieve two rows:

```
type          key     value
color_picker  value   cp_color
color_picker  label   cp_label
```

When I use json_extract methods, I end up retrieving the object `{"bind":"cp_color"}` from the json_tree table, but I also need to retrieve the data from the parent object.  I feel like I need to do some kind of union, but my attempts have so far been unsuccessful.  Any ideas here?

Note:  if the `{"bind":"<string>"}` object doesn't exist as a child of the parent object, I don't want any rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was on the right track and eventually figured out it.  I created a separate query for each of the items I was looking for, then `INNER JOIN`ed all the `json_tree` tables from each of the queries to have all the required fields available.  Then I `json_extract`ed the required data from each of the json fields I needed data from.  In the end, it gave me exactly what I was looking for, though I'm sure it could be written more efficiently.

For anyone interested, this is what hte final query ended up looking like:

```
SELECT IFNULL(json_extract(parent.value, '$.type'), '_window_'), child.key, json_extract(child.value, '$.bind') FROM (SELECT json_tree.* FROM nui_forms, json_tree(nui_forms.formJSON, '$') WHERE type = 'object' AND json_extract(nui_forms.formJSON, '$.id') = @sWindowID) parent INNER JOIN (SELECT json_tree.* FROM nui_forms, json_tree(nui_forms.formJSON, '$') WHERE type = 'object' AND json_extract(value, '$.bind') != 'NULL' AND json_extract(nui_forms.formJSON, '$.id') = @sWindowID) child ON child.parent = parent.id;
```

If you have any tips on reducing its complexity, feel free to comment!